# Meteor FS.Collection image doesn't render on upload

Tags: javascript, mongodb, image, meteor

Whenever I upload an image with FS.Collection using FileSystem, the image doesn't renders and I get a 503 error. But if I refresh the page the image will render and I get no error. So I had to to set that images path to a public folder using `ostrio:meteor-root`, so whenever I upload an image, the page refreshes. I'm fetching the image URL from a `Mongo.Collection`, not from my `FS.Collection`.
When I upload an image I store the url on Adverts:

```
    "_id" : "knCMZPK8RrY5Y7GQo",
    "reference" : 102020026,
    "pics" : {
    "pic" : [ 
             {
              "url" : "http://localhost:3000/cfs/files/Images/6fHhBT3ky5iAJnQfw"
             }
           ]
    },
```

Images.js:

```
    var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("Images", {
      path: Meteor.absolutePath + '/public/uploads'
    })
    Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
      stores: [imageStore],
      filter: {
          allow: {
              contentTypes: ['image/*']
      },
    }
});

  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Images.allow({
      insert: function(userId, party) {
          return true;
      },
      update: function(userId, party) {
          return true;
      },
      download: function(userId, party) {
          return true;
      },
      remove: function(userId, party) {
          return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Image not rendering:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

Instead of using FS collection I switched to ostrio:files.
Since I wanted to just upload the images to the document that I was updating (I have a `reactive-table` with my collection data, each row is clickable and contains a document, when I click a row I use `iron:router` to navigate to a page with `AutoForm` that updates that single document) I make a Meteor.call in the client to send the document _id to the server.
`Meteor.call('docId', this._id)`

It seemed like the image wasn't rendering because it was creating the thumbnail before finishing the upload.
So to fix this I made a `afterUpload` call back server-side on `docId Method`:

```
FSCollection.off('afterUpload')
FSCollection.on('afterUpload', function(fileRef){
  Update Mongo.Collection (...)
}
```

If I don't use .off before .on it keeps incrementing the time that the code inside the callbak is executed. When the first image is uploaded the code executes correctly, when the second one is uploaded the code is executed twice and so on.